# Data Validation between workbooks in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-query

I've been having some trouble moving data from one source Spreadsheet to another, and having my formulas work. An overview of what I'm trying to do is have Spreadsheet 2 (the active document) pull information from Spreadsheet 1 (the source document). The code I made and was using before looked into a data validated dropdown list and then auto populated a new dropdown list. I want to automate the 1st data validated column and then have the same code run. I've put the code I'm having trouble with below. I am pretty new to this so any help would be much appreciated.

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1APLcwkIE2EqVSS6Zongy799yg4z2tAN9J7h3jlJoBgQ").getSheetByName("Master List");

  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();


  var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1) {
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

  if(makeIndex != 0) {
    var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);

  }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't find any script very easily but I found an add on that helped so much with this! Use SheetGo for anyone who has a similar issue, if your looking for an easy answer!